# iOS Google Analytics Crash report

Tags: ios, sdk, google-analytics, crash-reports

Does anyone know when GoogleAnalytics iOS SDK v3 sends the crash to their servers (when app is on AppStore)?
Does it send when the app crashes, or when the user reopens it?

The problem is that, I'm viewing a lot of crashes from a bug that I think I solved, and on HockeyApp I'm not receiving anymore of these.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some points:

1. Crash reports are usually send the next time the app starts. Trying to send them at crash time may cause big harm to an app and its data. As far as I know GoogleAnalytics only sends reports on the next startup.
2. Google Analytics can only catch crashes caused by exceptions! In addition, any other exception handler will **NOT** be able to catch the exception! This is why you only see reports in Google Analytics but not in HockeyApp. This will happen with any other 3rd party SDK too. Usually the last crash reporting SDK you setup in your app wins.
3. You can test this yourself by using the [CrashProbe](https://github.com/bitstadium/CrashProbe/) open source project and include the SDK or SDKs you want to use. And then monitor the behavior for various crash types.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I hope that Analytics is sending previous crashes from users that are reopening the app.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, Google Analytics is not good in capturing crash report as I think the crash report might not be real time . Personally, I like bugsense and I am using paid version of [Bugsense](https://www.bugsense.com/). Its free version is good for most apps as well. May be you can try out the free version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that; But what I need to know is if GA sends the crash on app restart or when it crash.. :/

Comment: I tried to find info on that just now but I couldn't find anything related to that.

Comment: Bugsense is also using PLCrashReporter, just as HockeyApp is doing. There won't be a different behavior on receiving crash reports or not between the two. So when setting up Google Analytics after any of the two SDKs will cause both not to get any exception crashes any longer. This is a general issue.